# Limit the amount of current passing through a circuit to a set threshold?

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, circuit-protection

Here's the situation: I've added an aux input to an old hifi system by tapping into the circuit previously used by the magnetic read head of the hifi's built-in 8-track player. That part works pretty well, as both a 3.5mm headphone jack and the read head have 3 wires: left, right, and ground. I just switched them out and it worked as expected

The problem (I think) is that a modern cellphone pushes more power to the headphone port than the 8-track read head ever intended. Unless I turn my phone's volume way, way down, the sound is horribly distorted. I'm worried its probably not good for the circuit either.

I've thought about putting some resistors inline, but I have no idea what they should be. I'm not an electrical engineer - just took a handful of electrical course while getting a comp sci degree.

Is there some kind of simple device i can put inline to limit the power coming from the aux input? Ideally it would be something that blocks all voltage above a certain threshold.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some kind of simple device i can put inline to limit the
>   power coming from the aux input? Ideally it would be something that
>   blocks all voltage above a certain threshold.

A simple [attenuator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuator_(electronics)) with two resistors configured as a voltage divider will reduce the signal level and prevent overloading, but the sound will probably be muffled due to greatly accentuated bass and reduced treble. Why? The two graphs below (both scanned from National Semiconductor Audio Handbook 1978 edition) show the typical output of a tape head and frequency response of the associated tape pre-amp.

[image]

[image]

The tape head uses a coil to read the signal off the magnetic tape. Since magnetically induced voltage is proportional to frequency, the tape head output has a steeply rising frequency response until dropping off when the magnetic domains on the tape become smaller than the head gap. To compensate for this the tape pre-amp has the opposite response, with a very high gain at low frequency sloping down to lower gain at high frequency.

When the tape head and pre-amp are combined the overall frequency response is relatively flat. But your phone output already has a flat frequency response, so an attenuator which reduces the level equally at all frequencies will cause high frequencies to be ~30dB down at the output of the pre-amp.

For overall flat frequency response your attenuator needs to mimic the frequency response of the tape head, as well as reducing the signal level. This can be done by adding a capacitor in series, which creates a 'high pass filter' that progressively attenuates lower frequencies. We want this to start happening below ~2kHz, with a loss of ~30dB above it.

30dB loss corresponds to a voltage divider ratio of \$\sqrt{\log_{10}^{-1}{(30/10)}} = ~31.6\$, which can be achieved with standard resistor values of eg. 10kΩ and 330Ω. The 'cutoff' frequency of an RC filter is \$fc = 1 / (2 \pi RC)\$. The input resistance of your voltage divider is 10.33kΩ, so the capacitance required for 2kHz is 1/(2π*2000*10330) = ~7.7nF. Using the nearest standard value of 8.2nF the circuit looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f54u7r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which produces this frequency response:-

[image]

A 'Hi-Fi' tape pre-amp will also boost higher frequencies above ~6kHz to compensate for tape head roll-off at the upper end. We can reproduce this characteristic by adding a capacitor across the attenuator output to form a low pass filter. With 47nF in parallel with R2 the response looks like this:-

[image]

These values provide a starting point, but may not be the best for *your* amplifier. Feel free to change them if you find the level is too high or low or the frequency response doesn't suit your tastes.

Comment: Wow! You sir are a wizard! I messed around with car audio a fair bit as a teenager, so the stuff about the frequency response on the tape head makes perfect sense - I've just been using the bass and treble controls of the unit to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a resistive attenuator in line with the higher input. You might use two separate input jacks, one for the tape player input and one for the phone input. You place one resistor in series with the signal then another resistor following that connecting to ground. Often the resistor to ground is the higher value, (depending on the amount of attenuation you want).  Use an identical circuit for the other channel.

You should be able to see that if you were to use the same value resistor for both positions you would reduce the signal voltage by half, (with some dependence on the impedance of the amplifier input). You might initially try resistor values of 2.2k in series and a 10k to ground. Testing will help find the optimum values. Don't make the grounded resistor too low as this might cause problems.

If you don't want to use two input jacks you could use just one and add a small switch in the attenuator circuit to enable/disable it. Without the switch (or the extra jack) you still might be able find a middle range level that allows both the high and low level signals to sound satisfactory.

If you were to use a variable resistor for the series part you would effectively have a volume control.  You could use this arrangement to find a comfortable value then replace it with a fixed value, or just the variable part in place for future adjustments.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2dayn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! To be clear, ive disconnected the tape head, and plugged the aux in it's place. The hifi has a record player, am/fm, and 8-track. The tape head just connected to the board using a standard 3-pin connector, so i unplugged it, and replaced it with the aux in. I don't have any tapes, so i won't miss it.